# ¿Como importar atributos de productos en Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, excel, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de importar todos los atributos de los productos a Woocommerce y me surgen varios problemas ya que los atributos me vienen todos en una misma celda y delimitados por ":" y ";"

```
Ej:"Color:Azul;Tipo:USB;Tecnologia:Directa;".
```

¿Como puedo importar esto a Woocommerce?¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta usando "maybe_unserialize()", es una función que incluye wordpress, con esta función puedes extraer posible data "serializada".
Ejemplo:  $data = maybe_unserialize($atributos); 
Dependiendo de qué cosa entra a la función ('un string', 1232, '{"foo:bar; "}') esta devuelve un objeto que representa los datos que encontró.